# firemonkey canvas paint repeatedly circles onmousemove

Tags: firemonkey

I am using Delphi 10.4 and Delphi XE8 for educational purposes.

I made a canvas painting app for free hand drawing. In the `OnMouseDown()` event I draw an ellipse at mouse position and I want to draw more ellipses in the `OnMouseMove()`  event. But, on drawing to the canvas, there are blank parts between ellipses. I want to draw repeatedly without blank parts. How can I do that?

[image: image of problem]

Comment: Perhaps you could take a small snip of your drawing so we could see exactly what kind of 'blank parts' you are talking about. Also include your code that actually draws the circles, the `OnMouseMove()` code.

Comment: Thanks for the image, but the code?

Answer (score 1):

As you did not provide any code, I made this up quickly. This code is only to demonstrate usage of line drawing instead of repeatedly drawing circles to make a line. Drawings made with this code are not persistent.

If you can draw lines (with a round `StrokeCap`) instead of circles, it becomes quite easy as follows:

Save the position of the `OnMouseDown` event in a pair of `singles`, e.g. as fields of the form:

```
private
  xold, yold: single;
  Drawing: boolean;  // to indicate that we should be drawing in the `OnMouseMove` event

procedure TForm65.PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  Drawing := True; 
  xold := X; yold := Y;
end;
```

In the `OnMouseMove` event get the `xold`, `yold` values to two local singles (say `xpre`, `ypre`) and set `xold`, `yold` to current `X`, `Y`. Then draw a line from `xpre`, `ypre` to current `X`, `Y` position

```
procedure TForm65.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  xpre, ypre: single;
begin
  if Drawing then
  begin
    Canvas.BeginScene;
    try
      xpre := xold; 
      ypre := yold; // fetch previous position
      xold := X; 
      yold := Y;   // store current position for next event
      
      Canvas.StrokeThickness := 10;
      Canvas.StrokeCap := TStrokeCap.Round;
      Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red;

      Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(xpre,ypre), PointF(X, Y), 1); // draw line from prev pos to current
    finally
      Canvas.EndScene;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Reset `Drawing` in the `OnMouseUp` event

```
procedure TForm65.PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  Drawing := False;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. But the quality is not good for drawing. how can i have smooth drawing or change drawing pen type?

Comment: Well you asked: *I want to draw repeatedly without blank parts. How can I do that?* The line quality seems to me as good as yours, no? How is it worst? Anyway, I answered the question you asked, didn't I.

Comment: really thanks. I'll ask a new question. why this code doesn't run on android. how can i run the code in android.

Comment: Oh, you should actually not use this code. I wrote it because you did not show your code, and just to demonstrate the usage of line drawing instead of drawing circles. The drawing is not persistent (e.g. on Windows, minimize the form and then show it again and you will see what I mean). Use your own drawing code but apply the line drawing instead of the circles.

Comment: If you want to avoid the stroke looking like a polyline with straight sections then you could create a path instead and use CurveTo or SmoothCurveTo. You would need to keep a history of the last few cursor positions to use as the control points in the curve. This would basically join up the cursor points with a spline. There's no higher quality method than that since there's no way of knowing where the cursor was between mousemove samples.

Comment: But you would only notice the improvement when moving the cursor at very high speed, so doesn't seem worth it. Most drawing programs such as Paint clearly use a linear polyline method just like in Tom's answer.